# Damaged image in video view Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am developing rtsp video player app. I used default videoView widget for my goal. My code as below :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videoView;
    String path;
    Button btn;
    EditText editText;
    MediaController mediaController;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                path=editText.getText().toString();
                Uri video = Uri.parse(path);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and activity_main :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.yonder.denemetahtasi4.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Video is starting but image is damaged as shown below picture :

[image]

Where is my mistake ?  Maybe I should use library for this ?

Comment: Though I am not sure where your issue may be with this.I have never really had a good experience with the VideoView and MediaPlayer.However you may want to check a library called ExoPlayer. Its open source. It is a little bit more work to implement but works much better.

Comment: Could you please update your question with your video stream format?

Comment: thanks for advice @Devsil I don't know video stream format :/

Comment: You can get that kind of information from using the MediaMetaDataRetriever class. You can get things like MIME type, duration, height,width, bitrate, etc, for the video you are trying to play.

Comment: file format of video is  .H264